# using pd.grouper to group by n minutes each

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below
I want to groupby class,subclassadn describe D column for each hour interval

```
A,B,C,D
06-JUL-2017 09:15:00,class1,subclass1,3
06-JUL-2017 09:16:00,class1,subclass2,4
06-JUL-2017 10:15:00,class2,subclass1,5
06-JUL-2017 10:17:00,,class2,subclass2,7
```

I used :

```
`df.groupby(['B','account'],pd.Grouper(freq='60T'))['D'].describe().astype(int)`
```

But how do i tell Groper that it has to take times from A column and then apply frequency interval of 60T.

Expected op:(similar to)

```
class1 subclass1 9:15    
                 10:15
       subclass2 9:15
                 10:15
class2 subclass1 9:15
                 10:15
       subclass2 9:15
       subclass2 10:15
```

I tried `times = pd.to_datetime(df.A)` which takes some time (maybe becasue there are multiple same timestamps like 9:15:00, 9:15:00) 
I then tried `df.groupby(['B','C'],pd.Grouper(level=times,freq='15T'))['D'].describe().astype(int)`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the key parameter:

```
s ='''A,B,C,D
06-JUL-2017 09:15:00,class1,subclass1,3
06-JUL-2017 09:16:00,class1,subclass2,4
06-JUL-2017 10:15:00,class2,subclass1,5
06-JUL-2017 10:17:00,class2,subclass2,7'''
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(s))

df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])

df.groupby(['B', 'C', pd.Grouper(freq='60T', key='A', base=15)]).describe()
Out: 
                                         D                                  
                                     count mean std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
B      C         A                                                          
class1 subclass1 2017-07-06 09:15:00   1.0  3.0 NaN  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
       subclass2 2017-07-06 09:15:00   1.0  4.0 NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
class2 subclass1 2017-07-06 10:15:00   1.0  5.0 NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0
       subclass2 2017-07-06 10:15:00   1.0  7.0 NaN  7.0  7.0  7.0  7.0  7.0
```

You can programmatically obtain the base parameter from the first observation ([thanks to @MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080828/using-pd-grouper-to-group-by-n-minutes-each/45081162?noredirect=1#comment77134906_45081162)):

```
base = df.loc[df.index[0], 'A'].minute
df.groupby(['B', 'C', pd.Grouper(freq='60T', key='A', base=base)]).describe()
```

Comment: I'd also use: `base=df.loc[df.index[0], 'A'].minute`... ;)

Comment: @ScottBoston, it's not in the docs, but you can find it in the source code

Comment: @ayhan Got it.   Thank you.